# UDP packets dropped with `ctstate=INVALID`, but meanwhile its connection `[ASSURED]` in conntrack list

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, udp, netfilter

I have my router connecting to a remote VPS as so-called 'VPN' that is based on UDP protocol, then the VPS traffic slows down in few seconds after a new reboot.

I can see a huge amount of incoming reply packets dropped at `mangle PREROUTING` stage:

```
pkts bytes target        prot opt in     out     source               destination
327K  489M LOG_AND_DROP  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
```

and in `dmesg`:

```
IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=52.220.151.177 DST=10.17.175.251 LEN=1496 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=49 ID=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=4444 DPT=28317 LEN=1476
```

> only for example, `52.220.151.177` is the VPS IP and `10.17.175.251` is my gateway IP.

but in `conntrack` list, I found the UDP connection (pseudo-state) is already `ASSURED`:

```
udp      17 118 src=10.17.175.251 dst=52.220.151.177 sport=28317 dport=4444 src=52.220.151.177 dst=10.17.175.251 sport=4444 dport=28317 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
```

here is my `iptables` config:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [-:-]
:INPUT ACCEPT [-:-]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [-:-]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [-:-]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT DROP [-:-]
:FORWARD DROP [-:-]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [-:-]
-A INPUT -i ppp0 -j -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [-:-]
:INPUT ACCEPT [-:-]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [-:-]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [-:-]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [-:-]
:TPROXY_MARK - [-:-]
:OUTPUT_MARK - [-:-]
:LOG_AND_DROP - [-:-]
-A LOG_AND_DROP -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-tcp-sequence --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options --log-uid
-A LOG_AND_DROP -j DROP


-A PREROUTING -i ppp0 -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j LOG_AND_DROP         <---------HUGE AMOUNT OF HITS


-A PREROUTING ! -i ppp0 -j TPROXY_MARK
-A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
-A OUTPUT -o ppp0 ! -p icmp -j OUTPUT_MARK
-A TPROXY_MARK -m set --match-set whitelist dst -j RETURN
-A TPROXY_MARK -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port 1080 --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --tproxy-mark 0x1/0xffffffff
-A TPROXY_MARK -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port 1080 --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --tproxy-mark 0x1/0xffffffff
-A OUTPUT_MARK -m set --match-set whitelist dst -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT_MARK -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
COMMIT
```

any ideas?

i was expecting the ctstate of incoming UDP packets to be valid because the connection record exists in conntrack list.